Why does the DecisionTreeClassifiers accuracy change when we do these changes?
I was training a model using DecisionTreeClassifier and just like the LinearRegression / LogisticRegression algorithms testing and training datasets I use the 2D array for X values and 1D array for y values[y.values] but the accuracy [using .score()] was 75% this way but when I didn't use change the y values to a 1D array the the accuracy went up to a 100% why did it happen?
Training:
X = new_df.drop('salary_more_then_100k', axis='columns')
y = new_df.salary_more_then_100k

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

Tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
Tree.fit(X_train,y_train)

The above give 100% accuracy in my Test Dataset but
If i train like this [y.values]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y.values)

then the accuracy drops to 75% why?

Try setting a random_state. It will ensure that your split is the same.
Also, try printing y and y.values to see any differences. Maybe .values is resetting the indexes or something like that.
Finally, ensure that you're creating a new decisiontreeclassifier at each run, to not take previous training.
Also, a 100% accuracy is quite unlikely

Did it helped solving your issue ? Or are you still facing it
